# Are type-C doors plug doors?

Tags: aircraft-design, cabin-pressure

As I understand from the answer to this [questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/how-does-the-hinge-mechanism-of-plug-type-pressure-doors-work), plug doors are larger than the hole they mus fit in so that they are plugged thanks to air pressure, leading to several advantages. Then, I found this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dykoPn5tgEU) of a type-C door operating. This door does not seems larger then the hole it must fit in and that confuses me.

- Is this a plug-door?
- Is there something I miss?
- Is there other types of door that are not plug-door, or that are plug-door but don't look like plug-door?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, they are not. Most (not sure if all) Airbus door are **not** plug-type. And neither are *cargo* door on most Boeing types.