# Can Airbus A320 doors be opened mid-flight?

Tags: safety, airbus-a320, cabin-pressure, doors

Today I learned how airliner doors are typically an outward facing plug and cabin pressure would make them nearly impossible to open mid-flight.

It's easy enough to see that for the shape of [Boeing 737 doors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxzLNBlDVbE), for example.

But looking at [this video of the A320 door operation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rOI-4oGj7chttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rOI-4oGj7c), it doesn't exactly look like it forms a plug.  So if it were unlatched while the cabin is pressured, would it get pushed open?

Comment: related: [Are type-C doors plug doors?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12267/3394) and [What fail safe protections exist to prevent non-plug type cabin doors opening in flight?](/q/27763/3394)

Answer (score 5):

It's a plug door.  The door nestles behind an array of cleats and a set of L shaped guide tracks and has to move up some distance, as you can see in the video, to clear the cleats and exit the L track.  When it's dropped into the locked position, it's not dependent on any moving parts to resist pressure because it settles behind the fixed cleats in the outer frame.  The cleats in the door bear on the ones in the frame to resist outward pressure and the door is opened by lifting it to mis-align the cleats so the door cleats clear the frame cleats. That makes it a plug door.

It looks like there are other levers and cams to assist with the door pull-in, and probably some form of locking pin(s) to block vertical movement when latched. If the door was, say, 36 inches wide by 80 inches high, at an 8 psi cabin pressure differential, there is about 23000 lbs pushing on it, so you won't be moving it unless you are The Hulk.

The [CRJ Regional Jet main pax doors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4XSBfTM7_g) are an example of non-plug doors that just pull in flush on a simple hinge at the bottom, and latching shear pins extend into holes in the door frame.  This door is dependent on the shear strength of the movable pins, and the shear loads when pressurized pretty much weld the pins in place.

Comment: Are you sure those are plug-doors? I thought [A320 family doors were type-C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vbm8MpC0e1o) which [are not plug doors](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12267/3394).

Comment: It operates the same as the door in the first video, with the same L tracks and perimeter fittings, but a bit smaller with different contours. It has to move up to clear a set of fixed cleats in the frame.  When closed, pressure is pushing the fittings on the door against the fittings of the frame, making it a plug door.  The fact that that skin surface of the door is not larger than the fuse opening is irrelevant. The structural load paths are door statically pushing against fuselage.On the CRJs, the right side service door works the same as these doors, but the main pax door is a non-plug...

Comment: ...that depends mostly on 6 shear pins operated by a complex assembly of levers and bellcranks, and is a nightmare to rig.  That door just moves straight out with no vertical or lateral movments because the shear pins, a pull-in cam at the top, and the piano hinge at the bottom hold the door against cabin pressure, and the shear pins completely retract when opening to allow the door to swing straight out.

Comment: Does that mean the answers in the link question was wrong 5 years ago?

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: I figured there's something subtle about the way that door works!  This makes we wonder if it's more prone to leaking air pressure than a 737 door.

Comment: Depends on the type of seal system being used.  You can often see inflatable seal systems that use bleed air for inflation, that retract into a groove in the door frame and extend out when inflated to bridge the gap.  The RJ's door seal is a passive tubular gasket that presses against a ridge in the frame perimeter, with little vent holes that are open to the cabin side of the ridge, so cabin pressure provides some positive inflation pressure to push the tube against the ridge in the frame.  Works OK and doesn't require an inflation system.  Leaking doors seals can make quite a racket.

Comment: @JohnK I'm confused. Your answer begins by stating the A320 is fitted with plug doors while it seems to be fitted with type-C doors which are not plug doors. What am I missing?

Comment: I was randomly googling this again and I did find reports of doors violently opening due to residual cabin pressure straight from the horse's mouth: https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/preventing-violent-door-opening-due-to-residual-cabin-pressure/  So I guess it's possible up to a certain point, if not at full cabin pressure.

Comment: In that link it talks about checking an inward opening door to make sure there is no cabin pressure.  On a lift-up outward opening plug door, I imagine that when the pressure is down to a fraction of a psi, you can work the linkage of a lift up door with the leverage of the actuating lever, then once it's clear that residual pressure is enough to fling it out.

Comment: If the door is not larger than the opening, I don't see anything that prevents the door from being opened when the pressure pushes the door out and the operator doesn't need to pull it in first.

Comment: @RonenFestinger there are lug projecting from the frame that align with mating lugs on the door when it drops into place. When the door is raised the lugs are offset so the ones on the door can get past the ones on the frame.

Comment: @JohnK but what prevents it from being opened when in air? The pressure prevents the door from being pulled in, not from being pulled up and out.

Comment: The door is being pushed against the lugs attached to the fuselage. It has to move up so each lug on the door clears its mate on the fuselage.  But you won't be able to slide the door up off the retaining lugs with the leverage provided by the actuating system when there is 8 psi pushing on 3000 square inches. 11-12 tons or so. And the linkage may require the door to move in slightly, make it even more impossible.  Some doors aren't even plug doors, they're held closed by shear pins. You can't work the mechanism to withdraw the shear pins when the pressure differential is present.