# What are the differences between types I, II, and III emergency doors?

Tags: aircraft-structures, doors

What are the differences between types I, II, and III emergency doors?

Comment: this helps? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12830/1467

Comment: The answer suggested by @Federico mentions this FAR: [§25.807   Emergency exits](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c3e5e64205841639a4efcd8ef5fad806&node=se14.1.25_1807&rgn=div8) for the US/FAA.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, this question is only for emergency doors, and not limited to the US.

Answer (score 8):

The major difference is size.

[FAR part 25.801](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title14-vol1/xml/CFR-2011-title14-vol1-sec25-807.xml) defines them as:

> (1) Type I. This type is a floor-level exit with a rectangular opening
> of not less than 24 inches wide by 48 inches high, with corner radii
> not greater than eight inches.
>
> (2) Type II. This type is a rectangular
> opening of not less than 20 inches wide by 44 inches high, with corner
> radii not greater than seven inches. Type II exits must be floor-level
> exits unless located over the wing, in which case they must not have a
> step-up inside the airplane of more than 10 inches nor a step-down
> outside the airplane of more than 17 inches.
>
> (3) Type III. This type
> is a rectangular opening of not less than 20 inches wide by 36 inches
> high with corner radii not greater than seven inches, and with a
> step-up inside the airplane of not more than 20 inches. If the exit is
> located over the wing, the step-down outside the airplane may not
> exceed 27 inches.

There is also a type IV:

> (4) Type IV. This type is a rectangular opening of not less than 19
> inches wide by 26 inches high, with corner radii not greater than 6.3
> inches, located over the wing, with a step-up inside the airplane of
> not more than 29 inches and a step-down outside the airplane of not
> more than 36 inches.

If you read the full text, you will also find definitions for ventral and tailcone exits. For pictures I refer you to [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12830/what-are-the-differences-in-door-types-in-a-commercial-airliner/27951?s=1%7C0.6386#27951).